# Attaching debugger to custom activity on local TFS server?

Tags: .net, tfs

I need to debug a custom TFS activity.  I am running TFS on my local box and need to connect to the process.  What is the process name I should connect to?

Comment: have a look at Ewalds 2010 description , still relevant. http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-12-How-to-debug-my-custom-activities.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process name is TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.  Running locally I am able to set a breakpoint in my custom activity and have it stop there.  The service will time out, so if you are debugging for too long, you will likely crash the process and have to restart it via the Services pane (called Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host 2013).